# How do I get the data from my component into html in Angular before the page gets displayed?

Tags: angular

I am trying to display values retrieved from my api in the component. By the time the API responds with the data, my page is getting displayed and I am never able to show the list of elements. Could you let me know how I can solve this and display the values in my html page?

Here is my api call

```
public searchTeamInfo(term: string): Observable<TeamInfo> {

        return this.http.get<TeamInfo>(`/api/${term}`);
    }
```

I am calling the api in my component.

```
 public associatedPodNames: Array<TeamInfo>;
 associatedTeamIds: [
                            "12345",
                            "45454",
                            "43543543"
                        ]

ngOnInit() {
             this.getTeamInfo();
            }

public getTeamInfo(): Array<IPodDetails> {
     for (let i = 0; i < this.associatedTeamIds.length; i++) {
    this.searchService.searchTeamInfo(this.associatedTeamIds[i]).subscribe(res => {
                                    this.associatedPodNames.push(res);
                                    console.log(this.associatedPodNames);

                                 },
                            );
                       }

            }
```

I am trying to display the values in my html page using the below code.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let pods of associatedPodNames">
    pods
</ng-container>
```

I am able to see result in my console, the list of associatedPodNames. Here is the sample result.

```
[{podId: "12345", podName: "sample1", podType: "Project Pod"},
{podId: "45454"podName: "sample2"podType: "Project Pod"},
{podId: "43543543", podName: "sample3", podType: "Delivery Pod"}]
```

The associatedPodnames shows as empty even though I see the pod information in the console. How do I fix this?

Comment: Try `{{pods.podName}}` within the container.

Comment: Hi Andy, Thank you for replying. I understand the display part. Sorry for not being clear. My issue is with the associatedPodnames. It always shows as empty instead of the result from the API. I can see it in console. But it just that it does not get the value html. Looks like the page is being rendered even before the value is set in component. I need help on getting the associatePodNames get the data from the component into my html page.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to render the results you need to use the `JSON pipe` and you need to use `{{}}` to bind your data.

The `JSON pipe` will show the entire structure of the object on your HTML
e.g

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let pods of associatedPodNames">
    {{pods | json}}
</ng-container>
```

or

use the properties of the object:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let pods of associatedPodNames">
    {{pods.podId}}
</ng-container>
```

You can use any property you want to display that is inside of the Object you want to render

Angular Docs
https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data

FYI there are several way to bind data into your HTML

Property Binding,Event Binding and Two-Way Data Binding.

Comment: Hi Patricio, Thank you for replying. I understand the display part. Sorry for not being clear. My issue is with the associatedPodnames. It always shows as empty instead of the result. I can see it in console. But it just that it does not display in html. Looks like the page is being displayed even before the value is set in component. I need help on getting the associatePodNames getting the data in my html page.

Comment: you can do that different ways you can use the `async` pipe or you can have an *ngIf checking if the value of the array is bigger than 0. If this doesn't work take a look to the ngAfterOnInit() lifecycle

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double curly braces like this : {{ pods.property }} to bind one way content

Answer (score 1):

You have `pods` referring to each object within the container. You need an angular expression {{ }} within the container to display output values:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let pods of associatedPodNames">
    <p>{{pods.podName}}</p>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 associatedTeamIds: [
                            "12345",
                            "45454",
                            "43543543"
                        ]

ngOnInit() {
             this.getTeamInfo();
            }

public getTeamInfo(): Array<IPodDetails> {
     for (let i = 0; i < this.associatedTeamIds.length; i++) {
    this.searchService.searchTeamInfo(this.associatedTeamIds[i]).subscribe(res => {
                                    this.associatedPodNames = this.associatedPodNames.concat(res);
                                    console.log(this.associatedPodNames);

                                 },
                            );
                       }

            }
```